# Cypress not targeting and changing the Vuetify v-data-table component's "rows-per-page"

Tags: vue.js, testing, vuetify.js, cypress

The Vuetify v-data-table component has a rows-per-page select box at the bottom of the table, the problem is it's not a select box in html, so I'm having a ton of trouble testing the changing of options using Cypress, I've got as far as this piece of code:

```
cy.get('#app > div.v-application--wrap > main > div > div > div > div > div.container > div > div > div.pa-5.v-card.v-sheet.theme--light > form > div:nth-child(10) > div.v-data-table.v-data-table--dense.theme--light > div.v-data-footer > div.v-data-footer__select > div > div > div > div.v-select__slot')
            .trigger('mouseover').click();
cy.get('#app > div.v-menu__content.theme--light.menuable__content__active').children().trigger('mousedown', 0, 15).wait(500).trigger('mouseover').click();
```

However, all this code does is click on the select in the table footer, hover over an option, clicks, but then the option doesn't actually get changed, I would appreciate any help from people who've done Cypress testing on the Vuetify v-data-table component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change rows-per-page by typing an option, for example "All" into the right element. Finding the right element is a bit of trial and error.

```js
it('changes rows-per-page by typing option', () => {

  cy.contains('Rows per page')       // get the footer element 
    .find('.v-select__selections')   // this child element accepts keyboard input 
    .type('All{enter}')              // type in the option you want
    
  // Verify
  cy.get('.v-select__selection').should('contain', 'All')
  cy.get('tbody tr').should('have.length', 10)
})
```

The user can also use down arrow key on the list, so you can test that way.

Because the popup list is animated, the key thing is to add `.should('be.visible')` in order to wait for the list to appear in the DOM (otherwise the test is too quick)

```js
it('changes rows-per-page by using downarrow', () => {

  cy.contains('Rows per page')
    .find('i').click()            // open the list

  cy.get('[role="listbox"]')      // get the list that pops up
    .should('be.visible')         // wait for it
    .focus()                      // need to shift focus, by default it's on the input
    .type('{downarrow}')
    .type('{downarrow}')
    .type('{downarrow}')
    .type('{downarrow}')
    .type('{enter}')

  // Verify
  cy.get('.v-select__selection').should('contain', 'All')
  cy.get('tbody tr').should('have.length', 10)
})
```

The user could also use the mouse,

```js
it('changes rows-per-page by clicking option', () => {

  cy.contains('Rows per page')
    .find('i').click()

  cy.get('.v-list-item').eq(3)
    .should('be.visible')
    .click()
    
  // Verify
  cy.get('.v-select__selection').should('contain', 'All')
  cy.get('tbody tr').should('have.length', 10)
})
```